# pass php variable via AJAX with jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to send a variable `$stuff` frome `page.php` to `load.php` via POST

I have something like this in javascript

```
$.post("load.php", {'start': count }, function(data){
            $("#posts").append(data);

        });
```

I know I need to modify {'start': count } but im confused as to how to pass $stuff in since it isn't a javascript variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just echo it out.

```
$.post("load.php", {'start': '<?php echo $stuff ?>' }, function(data){
        $("#posts").append(data);

    });
```

Comment: cool thanks...so if i had multiple variables would it be {'var':'<?=$stuff1?>', 'var2':'<?=$stuff2?>'}